# liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: relation "container" already exists

Tags: database, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, liquibase

I'm working on an application with liquibase, spring-boot and hibernate.
The database used is PostgreSQL. In order to populate the DB at startup I configured a data.sql file in src/main/resources, containing some insert statements.
In addition, after the boot there is also liquibase trying to apply all the changesets, one of them being the creation of a table populated using the data.sql file. So I get the following non blocking error, when executing the `mvn` cmd to start the app:

```
2018-04-25 14:33:53.417 ERROR 11060 --- [neut-Executor-1] liquibase                                : classpath:config/liquibase/master.xml: config/liquibase/changelog/20180424154826_added_entity_Container.xml::20180424154826-1::jhipster: Change Set config/liquibase/changelog/20180424154826_added_entity_Container.xml::20180424154826-1::jhipster failed.  Error: ERROR: relation "container" already exists [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE public.container (id BIGINT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, description VARCHAR(2000), container_type VARCHAR(255), created TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE, CONSTRAINT PK_CONTAINER PRIMARY KEY (id))]
2018-04-25 14:33:53.453 ERROR 11060 --- [neut-Executor-1] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Liquibase could not start correctly, your database is NOT ready: Migration failed for change set config/liquibase/changelog/20180424154826_added_entity_Container.xml::20180424154826-1::jhipster:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: relation "container" already exists [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE public.container (id BIGINT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, description VARCHAR(2000), container_type VARCHAR(255), created TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE, CONSTRAINT PK_CONTAINER PRIMARY KEY (id))]

liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set config/liquibase/changelog/20180424154826_added_entity_Container.xml::20180424154826-1::jhipster:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: relation "container" already exists [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE public.container (id BIGINT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, description VARCHAR(2000), container_type VARCHAR(255), created TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE, CONSTRAINT PK_CONTAINER PRIMARY KEY (id))]
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:619)
    at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:51)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:79)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:214)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:192)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:431)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:388)
    at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.initDb(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:94)
    at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$0(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:77)
    at io.github.jhipster.async.ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor.lambda$createWrappedRunnable$1(ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: relation "container" already exists [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE public.container (id BIGINT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, description VARCHAR(2000), container_type VARCHAR(255), created TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE, CONSTRAINT PK_CONTAINER PRIMARY KEY (id))]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:309)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:55)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:113)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.execute(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1277)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1259)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:582)
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "container" already exists
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2455)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2155)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:288)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:430)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:356)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:303)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:289)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:266)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:262)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy129.execute(Unknown Source)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:307)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
```

What I'm thinking is that the hibernate executing the data.sql gets executed just a moment before the liquibase migration process, so maybe there should be a way to avoid this exception. Is it possible to force the execution of hibernate importing data.sql to happen after liquibase migration?

Comment: You could test if your assumption is correct by letting liquibase do the insert of the sql for you. IMHO it's generally a good idea to let hibernate do the schema validation only and let liquibase to the writing stuff.

Comment: I had some troubles to make liquibase working for loading the sql, so for time reasons I opted for hibernate to insert the data. However it would be also good to load the sql with liquibase. Any hint?

Comment: the `sqlFile` tag lets you do that: https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/sql_file.html

Answer (score 0):

you have to decide by which mechanism do you want to execute the changes. So you can use hibernate to create your tables and insert data or you can use liquibase to create you tables and data not both at the same time. What I was doing on previous projects was setting the hibenate to only validate mode `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate`and using liquibase to create tables and insert data.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem right now and your answer didn't help :( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64116221/change-set-classpathdb-changelog-v-1-0-01-changeset-users-table-xml2vladisl

Comment: create a question and provide more details, so somebody can help you.